# Create a menu as shown on this site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen this exact menu on two unrelated sites. How would I mimic it? Is it made with some popular framework?

Collapsed/normal state: 
[Normal State Image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?24c34e881d.png)

Here's the fly out state:
[Flyout State Image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/079d28d8a1.png)

You can see the menu used [on BNET](http://industry.bnet.com/technology/news-analysis/general-motors-augment-windshield/45004/?tag=river-2) and [on TechRepublic](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/networking/?p=2759&tag=content;col1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use YUI Menu to build it, http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/menu/

But honestly that looks pretty simple to implement with a floating div that you use jquery to show/hide when the share button is clicked.

Here is a quick example I coded up, http://jsfiddle.net/yhmrQ/

Just click share and the menu appears, click share again and it hides.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be generated by BNET:

http://blogs.bnet.com/intercom/?p=1764

Comment: My answer is an alternative,  but +1 for the exact match. Never seen that one before.

Comment: Me neither. I just guessed since Bnet was the first entry in the widget. Not so common... And apparently the guess was right :)

Comment: It's generated by BNET and also on Techrepublic.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, http://www.addthis.com/

Probably the most popular.